# не отображается поле сущности при запросе в java spring

Tags: java, html, spring

Помогите пожалуйста с проблемой. весь интернет переискал и ничего не нашел.

была у меня сущность soong с полями `id` `title` `textSoobg`. Добавил ещё одно поле `selected`. добавленное поле никак не отображается в запросе к контроллеру. если отдельно обращаться к этим полям то там все читается но в html запрос данное поле не передается. в базе данных все изменения внеслись все вроде правильно но никак не получается при запросе получить данное поле. в ответ только вносится первые три поля а 4 поле никак не отображается

модель

```
@Table(name="soong")
public class Soong {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String title;

    private String soongText;
    
    private Integer selected;
```

репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface SoongRepository extends JpaRepository<Soong, Long> {
    Optional<Soong> findById(int id);
    List<SoongView> findBy();
    Soong findSoongById(int id);
    Soong getSoongBySelected(int s);
}
```

контроллер

```
 @GetMapping("/soong/{soongId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Soong> getSoongById(@PathVariable int soongId)
    {
        System.out.println(soongId);
        Soong s = (soongRepository.findSoongById(soongId));
        int i = s.getSelected();
        System.out.println(i);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(soongRepository.findSoongById(soongId));
    }
```

при запросе в консоль выводит значение поля, но в html ответ его не вносит

Comment: Так может проблема в рендеринге html? Или Вы смотрите HTTP ответ каким-нибудь Postman'ом?

Comment: да я пытаюсь получить http ответ postman'ом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавили поле, но его значение не определено - `null`.

fasterxml по умолчанию в spring не включает в json такие поля.

Если вы желаете видеть что-то типа

```json
{
...
  "selected": null
}
```

то нужно использовать аннотацию `@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)`

Comment: а куда данную аннотацию вставлять нужно? В класс сущности или непосредственно на поле класса?

Comment: оба варианта возможны :)
На уровне класса работает на все поля, кроме тех  у который есть свой JsonInclude с отличающимся конфигом

Comment: Попробовал не получилось. Не знаю почему, но я просто удалил поле 'selected' и написал его повыше после поля 'id' и все заработало. не знаю с чем это связано. Но главное что заработало